# How to Pass DB Connection string as parameter in SSRS through URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

Our application is in .net and we are required to embedd and show case the SSRS reports from the .net application. Embedding was succesfull, now the data source is required to be made dynamic based on the logged in user, there respective server IP, DB name, user name and password is supposed to be passed to the SSRS. How can we achieve this?

Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Trying to get the connection string as a parameter from the URL but we are not sure how to accept the parameter. where should we get the control from

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the datasource passed to the report as a string already, then you can do this, but you must use an embedded datasource, not a shared datasource.

When designing reports from scratch you'll need to set the datasource's connection string as normal, just so field lists etc. all work, then once you have the report working, edit the datasource and hit the `[fx]` button next to the connection string.

Then just select your passed in parameter like below where myConnectionString is the passed in parameter.

[image]